# Using ngif else to display a different value in table

Tags: html, angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am getting data from the database. So in a particular column named card there exists only two types of values. "Debit" or "Credit". But in the backend I only receive values as "D" or "C".

```
`<div *ngIf="isBank">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead class="table_header">
               
                <tr>
            
               
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Bill</th>
                    <th>Card</th>
                 
                
                </tr>
        
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               
                <tr *ngFor="let bank of bankList; index as i">
                    
                    <td>{{  bank.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{  bank.bill}}</td>
                    <td>{{  bank.card}}</td>
                    
                         
                   
                    </tr>
             
               
            </tbody>
        </table>`
    </div>
  </div>
```

So here in the Card column I get only two values called as 'D' or 'C'. I get these values from the backend. So I want to change the value to 'Debit' if I get 'D' and 'Credit' if I get 'C'. This hads to be done within the template using ngif or whatever works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define an angular [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

`card-type.pipe.ts`:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'cardType'})
export class CardTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    if (value.toLowerCase() === "c")
      return "Credit";
    else if (value.toLowerCase() === "d")
      return "Debit";
    else
      return value;
  }
}
```

And in the template:

```
<tr *ngFor="let bank of bankList; index as i">                    
    <td>{{ bank.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ bank.bill }}</td>
    <td>{{ bank.card | cardType }}</td>
</tr>
```

`app.module.ts`:

```
import { CardTypePipe } from './card-type.pipe';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CardTypePipe
  ],
  imports: [..],
  providers: [..],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

If you think this pipe is an overkill, you can always use (I personally like my templates to be plain and simple):

```
<td>{{ bank.card === "D" | "Debit" : "Credit" }}</td>
```

Comment: I am getting the error " error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'cardType'.

                      <td>{{ bank.card | cardType}}</td>"

Comment: I am trying importing it from appmodule ts . I have used two export class component in same component ts one is for other another is for pipe. Am I doing it the wrong way

Comment: You can do it, but it is a best practice to separate them by files, see updated answer.

Comment: hey thanks for the help. I have upvoted ur answer. Can U like share ur e  mail id to ask doubts to u directly?

Comment: You can contact me via linkdin